# Docker container exit with error code error libcurl not found

Tags: docker, rust

I am building a container, you can see the docker file, its for rust app deployment on Argonaut. but its not able to start. Here you can see the Dockerfile.

```
FROM rust:1.64.0-buster AS builder
WORKDIR /app

ARG TOKEN
ARG DATABASE_URL

RUN git config --global url."https://${TOKEN}:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

COPY . .

ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI true

RUN rustup component add rustfmt
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install git wget ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release cmake libcurl4 -y

RUN cargo build

FROM debian:buster-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/debug/linkedin /app/target/release/linkedin
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

CMD ["/app/target/release/linkedin"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

It builds successfully but when it works it gets exit with error code 127.

```
linkedin-leadr-1  | /app/target/release/linkedin: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Have not found what's wrong with it, even though I am installing libcurl4. but my docker container is not able to find it. Can you please give me the solution?

Comment: It's hard to give you advise without being able to reproduce it. It would be much easier if you provided a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Also, please add `--release` to your `cargo build` step :D I'm sure you don't want to deliver unoptimized debug builds to your enduser

Comment: Actually it was --release but I removed it for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you install `libcurl4` in your build environment but not in your execution environment, that's most likely the reason.

There are two ways to solve this:

- Install `libcurl4` in your final image, or
- Link statically by replacing `cargo build` with

  ```
  RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
  RUN cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release
  ```

The `--release` flag should get added either way, as I'm sure you don't want to deliver unoptimized debug builds to your enduser ;)

Note that if you choose to install `libcurl4` in your final image, you need to clean up the apt cache afterwards, otherwise your image grows immensely:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes \
    libcurl4 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

---

The full Dockerfile with libcurl4 installed would then look like this:

```
FROM rust:1.64.0-buster AS builder
WORKDIR /app

ARG TOKEN
ARG DATABASE_URL

RUN git config --global url."https://${TOKEN}:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

COPY . .

ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI true

RUN rustup component add rustfmt
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install git wget ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release cmake libcurl4 -y

RUN cargo build

# Copy the libcurl shared library from the builder stage into the final container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && \
    cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 /usr/local/lib && \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4 /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so


FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes \
    libcurl4 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/target/debug/linkedin /app/target/release/linkedin
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

CMD ["/app/target/release/linkedin"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: How do I install libcurl in my final image?

Comment: Exactly like I showed ;) Now I added another full example that should maybe work. Can't test, though.

Comment: Thanks Got it, I am trying to build it but getting some configuration build errors.

Comment: @foragerDev Did you try building with `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`? Because in my honest opinion, this would be the better solution.

Comment: Can you please explain why it is better? I tried, but got bunch off issues, and then I just build it without musl. and It worked.

Comment: @foragerDev Sure, whatever works :) I prefer musl because it eliminates all unnecessary dependencies at link time. If you add the entire library to the Dockerfile, though, you have a bunch of stuff that potentially bloats the image but never gets used. But it's not that much of a difference, and more of a personal preference. And sure, if musl gives you compilation errors, use the other approach :)